# How to intercept file descriptor of file opened with inotify or others on access?

Tags: linux-kernel, coreutils, inotify, books, rust

I just finished an Operating Systems course at my University, and I want to start playing with systems level programs with Rust. One of things I'm looking for is how to intercept a file descriptor of a file opened in a folder, and swap the file it is pointing to a new file. I think I can figure it out with a bunch of the `inotify` tools and crates for Rust, as well as just calling some `libc` functions for syscalls myself, but I'm running into issues with understanding the Linux Virtual File System. Is there like a book that explains exactly how commands such as `find` operate on files, and how the files are structured? I downloaded the source code for the `coreutils`, but I'm struggling with determining what the file struct in Linux looks like. I know asking for books or resources is against some rules or something, but I can't seem to find a definitive resource on how the kernel and utilities work together. I'm just getting started with Open Source OS development, although I am very comfortable with using Unix-based systems. Any help guiding me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`inotify` will just warn your process something happens, then you can synchronise a distant file, a window content, trigger an anti-virus, etc. It will not permit the process to interfere with the opened file descriptor. Perhaps the closer thing you can do is creating a virtual file system : FUSE allows you to implement it in a user process. Such a file system will receive file accesses and can do whatever you want. The best think may be to get some open source examples and analyse them or open a tutorial (Google FUSE file system tutorial).

`find` is typically a program which use the `opendir` and `readdir` syscalls to get each directory content and some information about the files (`stat` may be needed too), it doesn’t need advanced API like inotify or FUSE.

You should me more precise about the question « how the file is structured ». Many systems show an API where a file is just a byte stream and the application does what it wants with this byte stream (read, write, seek).

If your question is about file system, the answer depends of the file system. On FAT, each directory entry point to the first cluster of its file (a set of block of fixed length), and a file allocation table indicates for each cluster which is the next. Some other file systems are more complex with a B-tree structure which point to each extent (a block number and a number of blocks). See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree A good operating system book will be far more detailed than a typical answer here. (You have a series of articles : understanding ext4 part1 in Google, then part2, … part6)